# Grouping blog posts under a single time_ago_in_words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

I am using

```
time_ago_in_words(post.created_at)
```

when listing my blog entries.

Instead of every listing having the time_ago_in_words listed in that posts title, I would like groups of different posts under a single heading, for example I might have one post under "30 minutes ago" and 8 posts under "one month ago"

Can anyone recommend the best way to do this please?

Answer (score 2):

Do you realize that `time_ago_in_words` is a method written on Ruby language so you can't use it in your sql-queries to perform groupings and count-calculations by DB?

If you've got a lot of posts than you have to craft some sql-query for grouping your posts.

But if you're telling that the amount of your posts isn't that huge than you can use the simple approach:

```
# in a controller
@posts_map = Post.order('created_at DESC').all.group_by{|post| time_ago_in_words post.created_at }

# in a view
- @posts_map.each do |time, posts|
  %h2 Created #{time} ago (#{posts.length}):
  - posts.each do |post|
    %h3= link_to post.title, post
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply jdoe, but i think you have miss-understood me. I have a blog front page listing all my posts, along with the time they were posted using time_ago_in_words. I want to avoid the situation where i may have 3 consecutive posts all with the same title "posted 1 month ago". What I want is to have a single title "1 month ago" with the three posts below it.

Comment: That's exactly what my example does! `Created #{time} ago (#{posts.length}):` shows title and `posts.each do |post|` cycles through this time group. Then the same for another time group.

Comment: Can we think of a SQL option or is there not really a way? I'm looking into this exact thing now.